# how to get a data from NCBI GEO via R getGEO

Tags: r

NCBI GEOデータベースから、GSE22216をRプログラミングにて、入手しようとしました。
以下のプログラムを実施しましたが、エラーがでてしまいました。
解決策をおしえてください。

```
gset2<-getGEO("GSE22216",GSEMatrix=TRUE)
```

エラーの内容

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE22nnn/GSE22216/matrix/
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov port 21: Timed out
```

Comment: タイトルも日本語で書いていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ウェブブラウザで [GSE22216_matrix](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE22nnn/GSE22216/matrix/) にアクセスできますか？